# MFSideMenu Landscape Mode issue

Tags: ios, mfslidemenu

my app is using MFSideMenu script to push a view from right and i have set it to auto open the left menu if the app is opened in landscape mode  , the problem is whenever i try to open app in landscape mode it shows black screen and i have noticed as i even slightly dropdown the notification bar it shows the rightmenu fine . The problem just happens in landscape mode and one its done it has no problems even when i rotate the app it works absolutely fine , just the opening app in landscape part is create issue for the first time .

Comment: Are you talking about the Default image being blank in landscape or the entire app is blank?

Comment: when i push the mfsidemenucontroller from the left it shows blank image rather then the uitableview in it , the whole is just fine

Comment: If it works correctly when you rotate the screen back and forth you could just call the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation manually for the appropriate orientation. It sounds like the layout just needs to re-layout.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same `issue` of `rientation`.

Use Another Option [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController). `Usage` is `similar` to `MFSideMenu`

`MMDrawerController` is a side drawer navigation container view controller designed to support the growing number of applications that leverage the side drawer paradigm. This library is designed to exclusively support side drawer navigation in a light-weight, focused approach while exposing the ability to provide custom animations for presenting and dismissing the drawer.